# Managed bean vs CDI

Tags: jsf, java

Сейчас учу JSF  по книги Java Server Faces. И вот не пойму, там они пишут: используйте бины CDI вместо managed bean, аргументируя тем, что последние ограничены. Кто знает, обьясните, в чем основная разница, недостатки и преимущества каждого. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Подобный вопрос возникал [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347374/jsf-backing-beans-managedbean-or-cdi-beans-named) . Там пишется, что в CDI ты можешь использовать практически любой класс, в то время как для использования в mb придется пользоваться классами с тэгом @ManagedBean.